# Running all Flutter unit tests from Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

1. In Visual Studio Code, I see no GUI option to run all my Flutter unit tests. I have to individually select each test file, right click, and choose either 'Start debugging' or 'Start without debugging.'
2. When the emulator is running, I am unable unable to do the above. I cannot run any unit tests from the GUI

My unit tests are located in the test directory and all end in '_test.dart'. To get around both of the above, I can run all the unit tests by doing `flutter test` from the terminal, but I was wondering if there was a GUI option.

This issue does not exist on Android Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this?
https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-21/

Add the following to your `launch.json` file. If you do not have a launch.json file, go to the Run view in VS Code and click `create a launch.json file`.

```
{
    "name": "All Tests",
    "type": "dart",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "tests/", // or test/foo for a subset of tests
}
```

Comment: I added that, but not all the tests are run. It only runs the tests that I had previously added to the "Test" tab (which I'm not sure how I did), and it only runs a portion of those tests.

Comment: This seems to work now. The tests are all run. Choose the config from the 'Run' tab and press go.